# Couchbase Lite Datastructure Appoarch

Tags: android, database-design, couchbase-lite

I have many data models. How should I approach when I create my Couchbaselite database? Should create multiple database for every model. Then how should I join them?

Example Object Model:

Restaurant

- Name
- Adress

Waiter

- Name
- Salary

`json String: [{ id=..., Name=Rest, adress={id=...,street=..}}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same database for multiple models, and when you want to join, you could use alias(`DataSource.database(db).as("main")`) from same database(below example `db`) and join using it.

Below is a swift example,

```
let q = QueryBuilder
        .select(SelectResult.expression(Meta.id.from("main")))
        .from(DataSource.database(db).as("main"))
        .join(
            Join.join(DataSource.database(db).as("secondary"))
                .on(Expression.property("prop1").from("main")
                    .equalTo(Expression.property("prop2").from("secondary"))))
```